# book or notes on linear programming for a professional mathematician

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, linear-programming, book-recommendation

I would like to have a dense and short **math** book on LP. I am not interested in storytelling nor why it is super useful for real world applications etc. Thanks.

Comment: are you looking for a book on modeling or on solution algorithms?

Comment: Are you interested in polyhedral theory?  linear programming duality? Conic linear programming?  The simplex method?  Interior point methods?  Computational Complexity?  There are many books written on each of those topics.  Most introductory books cover only a small subset of these topics.

Comment: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02591902